# check if table column has empty cell

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

in my case i have 3 columns, every column is dependent on previous one.
user must enter all cells in column 1 so column 2 be editable then he enters column 2 to make column 3 editable.
if he cleared cell then dependent columns should be disabled.

how could i handle it using JavaScript

please find below image :

[image]

Comment: it's ADF Application

Comment: i disable and enable it. but it needs me an action like clicking a button, 
so i am thinking in handling it using JS. but i don't know how to check if column has an empty cell.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your table cell will be a `af:input text` .
You don't need explicitly JS to achieve this as you can achieve it in ADF itself. So if you dont have requirement to do it in JS then you can try this below way. With Button we are having `action` or `actionListener` , same way we have `valueChangeListener` with `inputText`.

Suppose you are having 2 input text (2 cells in table).

```
 <af:inputText value="#{bindings.ESal.inputValue}"
              label="#{bindings.ESal.hints.label}"
              required="#{bindings.ESal.hints.mandatory}"
              columns="#{bindings.ESal.hints.displayWidth}"
              maximumLength="#{bindings.ESal.hints.precision}"
              shortDesc="#{bindings.ESal.hints.tooltip}" id="it11"
              autoSubmit="true" valueChangeListener="#{bean1.textChange}"
             >
  <f:validator binding="#{bindings.ESal.validator}" />
</af:inputText>
```

- Here make `autoSubmit = true` for the input text which will be
  changed.
- Use valueChangeListener event and create a method as `textChange` as
  shown above. It will be triggered whenever there is a change in your input text (on tab change also it will be triggered).

  ```
   <af:inputText label="Output label"  id="ol1" 
              partialTriggers="it11" binding="#{bean1.lbl}"
            disabled="true"/>
  ```
- This inputText is dependent on first one. It's disabled by default.
- Use PartialTrigger and assign first inputText in it.
- Create a binding for this inputText which can be used in managed
  bean.

  ```
    public void textChange(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
  // Add event code here...
  if(!(valueChangeEvent.getNewValue()==null || 
     valueChangeEvent.getNewValue().equals(""))) // checking input Text value
  { // if not null
      lbl.setDisabled(false);    //then enable it
      AdfFacesContext adfFacesContext = AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      adfFacesContext.addPartialTarget(lbl); // refresh the binding
  }
  else
  {
      lbl.setDisabled(true);    //else disable it.
          AdfFacesContext adfFacesContext = AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
          adfFacesContext.addPartialTarget(lbl);    
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

Enable the java RowImpl for your ViewObject So you can control the returned data in the getters