# Focus empty cell at ADF table

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf

i want to focus cell if it is empty and prevent user from leaving the cell until he enter value.

i tried some JS:

```
var flag = 0;
function setFocusFn(evt) {
    console.log("Inside setFocusFn"); 
        if (flag) return;
        flag=1;

    var element = evt.getSource();
    var val = element.getValue();
    var cid = element.getClientId();
    var regexp = /^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$/g;
    var result = regexp.test(val);
        if(val){
            if(result){
                valRounded = Math.ceil(element.getValue());
                evt.getSource().setProperty('value',  valRounded);
            }
        }

        if(val == null){  
            element.focus();
            //element.select();
            evt.cancel(); 
            setTimeout('flag=0', 1);
        }else{
            flag=0;
        }
}
```

it works but when i right click or click on any cell at any other column i lose the focus on the cell.

i used the flag as it entered on infinite loop.

Comment: Is it a table column ? or input text ?

Comment: @Shaili table column

Comment: Do you want it to be done in javascript only ? or you can do it in ADF also?

Comment: ADF or JS doesn't matter. 
but i tried ADF  using required or mandatory but didn't work

Comment: No it will not work. There is valueChangeListner attribute of table column. you need to write a function in that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53100030/check-if-table-column-has-empty-cell This is your question only. It is the same. See the answer in it. I have only posted and it's working in my case.

Comment: Have you tried it? Are you facing any issue in that?

Comment: can not use valueCangeListner as i need to check for null value .
VCL will only work when value entered in the cell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185413/discussion-between-shaili-and-amir-elsaeed).